# Azure CI/CD - Azure Private Npm Registry - Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net

Tags: azure, authentication, npm, azure-devops, private

We have a private npm registry (library) for our Angular UI because of this we can't run npm install before authenticating the private registry. The registry is in a different Azure organization. When I work on a local machine for the first time, I run this code, (npm install -g vsts-npm-auth --registry https://registry.npmjs.com --always-auth false) and then this code (vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc), then pop up appear and I need to input my credentials, like username and password after that I can now use npm install to install packages from my private registry.

In azure CI pipe-line there is no user interaction so what I did was, I created a service connection with username(organization username) and password(organization password) and the package URL which I have found in .npmrc file. I then use the service connection in NPM Authenticate Task to authenticate the registry but it throws me an error when npm install run. I have posted the error pic below. Can anyone please help me to authenticate the private registry to install packages. Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When the npm registry is in a different Azure organization, you should use Personal access token to Authenticate.

Login to the Azure organization where the npm registry resides, Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to create a Personal Access token with at least `read`permission of Packaging scope.

Then choose **Authentication Token** as the **Authentication method**, and type in the Personal Access token generated in above step.

[image]

Update:
**As it is described for task npm authenticate (for task runners) in below:**

> Don't use this task if you're also using the npm task. Provides npm credentials to an .npmrc file in your repository for the scope of the build. This enables npm task runners like gulp and Grunt to authenticate with private registries.

You can configure the authentication service connection in **NPM install** task directly. See below:

[image]

Comment: I have done as you mentioned but i am getting the same error.

Comment: You might need to authenticate the npm registry in npm install task. Please check out above update.

Comment: Hi @TayebHimel How does it go now?

Comment: I have done as you suggested but it is not working either but I have noticed one other thing when I select (Registry | Select here) I need to select the feed but I could not find a feed that has those libraries that need to authorize because of this i am getting different error.

Comment: The screenshot is incorrect. It should be `Registries in my .npmrc`. See above update. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Hi @TayebHimel Was above issue fixed, Any update for this case?